Why phpstan returns an error for a basic view?
I am using larastan 3.0 with laravel. The level is 9.
In this code :
return view('auth.change-password', [
        'user' => $user,
    ]);

I have this error :
 Parameter #1 $view of function view expects view-string|null, string given.
       argument.type

I do not understand why this error because the "view" method expects either a string or a null. In my case, the string 'auth.change-password' is supplied. So why this error ?

The error was obvious. The view did not exist !
I didn't know that PHPstan would go so far as to check the existence of resources.
